# C# Console App || Can i use ddMMyy as DayTime instead of dd/MM/yy?

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I'm asking the user for birthdate which is 6 digits without `/` and `-`. How can define datetime to read 6 digits `ddMMyy`??

```
WriteLine("Write Your birthday using unly number and 6 digits 'ddMMyy'")
string userinput = ReadLine();
DateTime bday = DateTime.Parse(userinput);
WriteLine($"Your birthday is: {bday}");
```

Outputs:

> Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String '041197' was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.

*No it's not a duplicate. This didnt answer my question "stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/…"
**But answers on this post solved it !***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In such a case, you might wanna use `ParseExact` and/or `TryParseExact` methods like `DateTime bday = DateTime.ParseExact("041197", "ddMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Thanks. My userinput is '041197'. 04 is day, 11 is month, 97 is year.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks i'll look.. where'd your comment go? :D

Comment: Use `ParseExact`.  See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Don't forget to add `System.Globalization` namespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    public class Test
    {
    public static void Main()
    {       
        CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en");
        DateTime dt =   DateTime.ParseExact("040415","ddMMyy", provider);
  Console.WriteLine(dt.Year.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect that fixed my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 CultureInfo info= new CultureInfo("en");
 DateTime birthDay=   DateTime.ParseExact("041197","ddMMyy", info);
 WriteLine($"Your birthday is: {birthDay}");
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.